# Change Text b/n Span Tag with has no id, in java script

Tags: javascript, tags, html

I have a span tag without an id

eg: `<span>Welcome</span>`

I have many span tags in the same web page.

Is there a way to access this span tag in the javascript and change the

"Welcome" to "something else"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no ID or other attribute you can select, then you can loop through all `<span>` elements looking for the exact text (via `.innerHTML` for example), like this:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
    if(spans[i].innerHTML == "Welcome") {       //is this the "Welcome" span?
        spans[i].innerHTML = "something else";  //change to new value
        break;                                  //hop out of the loop, we're done
    }
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WUxTD/1/).

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>

<script type="javascript">

var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
    if(spans[i].innerHTML == "Welcome") {
        spans[i].innerHTML = "a";
        break;
    }
}
</script>

<body>

<span>Welcome</span>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @sa2010 - your javascript needs to run *after* the elements are present in the page.  For example at the end of the `<body>` or on `window.onload`.